# How to get real password from Django rest framework ( JWT token ). For UserListView

Tags: django, jwt, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm new to this topic, I want to implement the output of users and their real passwords for admin access. At the moment I have this code, it displays encrypted passwords. How can I make the password that the user entered during registration appear in the field? Thank you in advance.

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = models.User.objects.all()
serializer_class = serializers.UsersListSerializer

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
first_name = models.CharField(('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = UserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.email)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    return self

@property
def token(self):
    return self._generate_jwt_token()

def _generate_jwt_token(self):
    dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)

    token = jwt.encode({
        'id': self.pk,
        'exp': dt.utcfromtimestamp(dt.timestamp())
    }, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')

    return token.decode('utf-8')
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

def _create_user(self, first_name, last_name, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False):
    if not first_name:
        raise ValueError('First name should be set')
    if not last_name:
        raise ValueError('Last name should be set')
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Email should be set')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        is_active=is_active,
        is_staff=is_staff,
        is_superuser=is_superuser
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)

    return user

def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, email, password=None):
    user = self._create_user(first_name, last_name, email, password=password, is_staff=True)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, email, password=None):
    user = self._create_user(first_name, last_name, email, password=password, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True)
    return user
```

**Now I have this**

```
[
{
    "email": "123@gmail.com",
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$216000$2HREtqWfeAGm$VKHOyaoXR9x+xIBrBuoaDEjnJx/6V+bNkw/Y0iSJhA0=",
    "first_name": "Kdhsdh",
    "last_name": "JKgfjgps"
},
{
    "email": "sebek@gmail.com",
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$216000$A0ms9j2nh3hJ$q9BS8LuwxiOdPpO36QzJHMCPnBMYfDnci51omfyS7oo=",
    "first_name": "Sebek",
    "last_name": "Bebek"
}
]
```

**I want to have this**

```
[
{
    "email": "123@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345678",
    "first_name": "Kdhsdh",
    "last_name": "JKgfjgps"
},
{
    "email": "sebek@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345678",
    "first_name": "Sebek",
    "last_name": "Bebek"
}
]
```

Comment: passwords are hashed, not encrypted and that's how it should be. Why would you want to see the real passwords? And how is the question related to JWT?

Comment: This is my homework api, I want to see the real password, for example, if I lose my password and don't remember it). I will be able to log in as an administrator and just remind myself.

Comment: as said above, the passwords are stored as hashes and thus can't be decrypted. I'm not a DRF expert, but I guess the framework doesn't offer any other option. Maybe you can circumvent the mechanisms and just store encrypted passwords but instead you can also learn how to work with the things like they are.

Comment: Okai, I understand, thx a lot.